# How to start the dictionary application after installation?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation, dictionary

I installed a dictionary application using this site: - http://www.noobslab.com/2011/07/install-offline-ubuntu-dictionary.html but after installation when I searched for it on / , I didn't see any application file that was to be launched (like I do for other applications). Could anyone help me open this application please? If not, is there any good dictionary app that I can install instead?

Comment: What happens when you type "dictionary" in the unity dash -- does it come up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any good dictionary app that I can install instead?

I would recommend the following:

1. [**Artha**](http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Home)

`sudo apt-get install artha`

[image]

1. [**GoldenDict**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/goldendict/)

`sudo apt-get install goldendict`

Install the copyright free GNU powered English dictionary

`sudo apt-get install dict-gcide`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded Artha and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You've followed a specific tutorial. How about the [follow up tutorial](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/howto-install-dictionary-in-ubuntumint.html)? ;)